# Kendo Ajax Grid Parameters with .Net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo grid in which I am trying to send additional data as a bool which I can use to filter the return data in my controller.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Securities_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, bool filter) {
    if (filter == true) // do something.
}
```

Read:

```
.Read(read => read.Action("Action", "Controller").Data("filterFunction"))
```

filter Function:

```
function filterFunction() {
    var filter = ($('#checkbox').is(":checked")) ? true : false;
    console.log(filter);
    return {
        filter: filter
    }
}
```

Checkbox event handler:

```
$('#checkbox').change(function () {
    $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
});
```

Any time the checkbox is changed it runs the change function which in turn calls the kendo grid to run the read function. The kendo grid also calls the filterFunction to get additional parameters. I can see that the filterFunction is indeed being called because a log the value of filter to the console. However once it gets back to the controller the value of the additional parameter is always null.

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm really not a fan of the wrappers for kendo, but all I'm noticing is a missing semicolon after your `return { filter: true }`. Also, have you tried passing a string or int just to see if it works? I haven't tried to reproduce what you have just yet.

Comment: On top of what @KSib said: I'm looking at one of my working implementations and I also do not semicolon the return statement, HOWEVER you MAY need to add it to the end of the function. Seems to be the only obvious difference from what I usually do to your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem that filter is a key word use in the kendo framework. So when I changed:

```
function filterFunction() {
    var filter = ($('#checkbox').is(":checked")) ? true : false;
    console.log(filter);
    return {
        filter: filter
    }
}
```

to:

```
function filterFunction() {
    var filter = ($('#checkbox').is(":checked")) ? "true" : "false";
    console.log(filter);
    return {
        shouldFilter: filter
    }
}
```

Also notice that you can only pass strings as parameters so I had to change the parameter in the controller to a string and the true/false value to strings in the JavaScript function above:

```
public ActionResult Securities_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, bool filter) {
    if (filter == true) // do something.
}
```

to:

```
public ActionResult Securities_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, string filter) {
    if (filter == "true") // do something.
}
```

That solved my problem.